# Сохранение токена в заголовке

Tags: javascript, vue.js, авторизация

Всем привет,у меня вот такая проблема,не получается сохранить токен в заголовке
Приходится вот так постоянно его задавать,но так не должно быть

```
 mounted() {
     axios.get('api/v1/inspection/script', {
       headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`,
       },
    })
       .then(response => (this.info = response.data));
  },
```

Вот код моей авторизации

```
const initialState = { token: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || '', status: '', hasLoadedOnce: false };

const getters = {
  isAuthenticated: state => !!state.token,
  authStatus: state => state.status,
};

const actions = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit(AUTH_REQUEST);
    axios({ url: 'api/v1/tokens', data: user, method: 'POST' })
      .then((resp) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        const token = resp.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('user-token', token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token;
        commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, resp.data);
        dispatch(USER_REQUEST);
        resolve(resp);
        VueNotifications.success({ message: 'Вход выполнен успешно' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        commit(AUTH_ERROR, err);
        localStorage.removeItem('user-token');
        reject(err);
        VueNotifications.error({ message: 'Неправильный логин или пароль' });
      });
  }),
  [AUTH_LOGOUT]: ({ commit }) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    commit(AUTH_LOGOUT);
    localStorage.removeItem('user-token');
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    resolve();
  }),
};

const mutations = {
  [AUTH_REQUEST]: (state) => {
    state.status = 'loading';
  },
  [AUTH_SUCCESS]: (state, resp) => {
    state.status = 'success';
    state.token = resp.token;
    state.hasLoadedOnce = true;
  },
  [AUTH_ERROR]: (state) => {
    state.status = 'error';
    state.hasLoadedOnce = true;
  },
  [AUTH_LOGOUT]: (state) => {
    state.token = '';
  },
};

export default {
  state: initialState,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Comment: Для удобства можете использовать библиотеку axios для vue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете указать [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) для axios:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const token = store.state.auth.token

  if (token)
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`

  return config
})
```

Можно еще использовать плагин axios для vue, вот ссылка на него: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-axios

Вот как с ним сделать:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAxios from 'vue-plugin-axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'

Vue.use(VueAxios, {
  axios, // указать саму axios библиотеку
  config: {
    // api URL
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
  },
  interceptors: {
    beforeRequest (config) {
      // берет токен из store
      const token = store.state.auth.token
 
      // если есть токен то ставит его
      if (token)
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
      
      return config
    }
  }
})
```

Теперь можно делать легко запросы:

```
// get запрос
this.users = await this.$get('api/get-users/')
// post запрос
this.users2 = await this.$post('api/get-users/')
```

Не нужно писать

```
import axios from axios

this.users = (await axios.get('api/get-users/')).data
this.users2 = (await axios.post('api/get-users/')).data
```

С этим плагином для vue можно делать все что на обычном axios но в удобном для vue виде.